# Visual Studio C# WPF run without debugging - nothing happens

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Visual Studio 2008, and I am learning the old "Hello World" application using a WPF application. When I click 'Start without Debugging' I see a window open for a half-second on my taskbar and then close.

I don't get any window that stays open with my application in it. I cannot figure out why this is happening. If I trying opening a windows form application everything runs fine.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code? The default WPF solution doesn't display this behaviour.

Comment: Can we see a code snippet? will make it a bit easier to determine the issue.

Comment: How have you created this application -- did you use the WPF Application template, or have you written a custom Main method to show the window?  What happens when you run under the debugger -- does it work?

Comment: check windows event viewer. Are there any crash exceptions in the application log ?

Go to visual studio --> debug menu --> exceptions. Check the managed exceptions and run your program. Does it exception and stop ?

Comment: The obvious question: what happens if you run the WPF application in the debugger?